# How to get the content right for better showing in google results

Tags: meta-tags, meta-description, meta-keywords

I am looking for basic help or guidelines for making my site earn better visibility in google and other search engine results. My site is a price-comparison engine for products so I want to know what shall feature in my meta keywords, meta description, images and content.

For example, you can think of Nokia Lumia 920 as one of the products.

Answer (score 1):

Your operating in a extremely competitive niche, you will need to focus on getting pages online when they are fresh. Maybe get price comparison pages up way before the product has actually been launched to the public.

While Meta's and Content is important I believe these are the least of your problem, there are hundreds if not thousands of websites operating in this scene. Your going to have to work extremely hard to make the website successful.

I would consider the following in order to get your website ranking:

- Research Tail-Long Keyword Phrases
- Focus on fresh content and have it online way before your competitions, even for models that are not publicly available to the product. On the page just have the specifications, estimated page and then with a disclaimer or some sort saying this product is due in month X.
- Focus on social media, still today many websites ignore the power of social media.

I'm not going to go into the use of the metas, and content as I'm sure you already know this and I believe the problem you face isn't so much your content but outsmarting your competitors.

Comment: Thanks mate. The tip is really nice and will incorporate the idea on my site. BTW do you think, I should use "product name", "price compare", "online retailers" keywords more than required. These terms are present in my pages but not bombarded. Mine is up to the point content and meta-tags

Comment: Keyword density has changed a lot of the years, its not as important as it used to be, and using to much just results in negative SEO. Generally it should be ok to repeat exact keywords twice on a 400-500 word page. But you should only use the keywords if it makes sense to your customers.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clearing the doubts. I was also skeptical about using keywords unnecessarily.